# Real-time feed Reactions - getstream-io

Tags: feed, getstream-io

I am implementing a facebook/linked-in like feed using getstream.io. Feed Structure is as below:

```
I have two feed groups;
     1. user (flat feed)
     2. timeline (flat feed)

Every user has an own user feed(user:userId) and a timeline feed(timeline:userId). 
timeline:userId follows user:userId
```

When a user put a post to user:userId then corresponding followers get real-time updates to their timeline:userId feeds. That part is working properly.

But when a user put an reaction(i.e. like) to a post, other users(those who has same post on their timeline) not getting any real-time update about that reaction.

So how can I achieve this using getstream.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a missing feature and it is being implemented at the moment.

Right now, while adding the reaction, you can add `targetFeeds` property which will create an activity on other listed feeds that references the reaction being created. It will trigger a real-time update since an activity is added on some feeds. On the client side, you can process this update and ignore the special activity if you want.

Comment: IS there an update to this? Has this feature been implemented?

Comment: Yes, it was implemented. I don't work at stream anymore so I suggest contacting support to get the feature enabled for your account.